# Is there a way to select all of a sub-list with shiny selectInput()?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app that utilizes a nested list within selectInput(). Is it possible to add the capacity to select all of the items in a specific sub-list?

R version 3.5.3
Shiny version 1.2.0

below is a very basic shiny app to illustrate the problem. in my actual use-case, the sub-lists are much longer than 4 items, so selecting each element would be time-consuming.

```
library(shiny)

east <- list("DAL" = "Dallas Cowboys",
             "NYG" = "New York Giants",
             "PHI" = "Philadelphia Eagles",
             "WAS" = "Washington Redskins")
north <- list("CHI" = "Chicago Bears",
              "DET" = "Detroit Lions",
              "GB" = "Green Bay Packers",
              "MIN" = "Minnesota Vikings")
south <- list("ATL" = "Atlanta Falcons",
              "CAR" = "Carolina Panthers",
              "NO" = "New Orleans Saints",
              "TB" = "Tampa Bay Buccaneers")
west <- list("AZ" = "Arizona Cardinals",
             "LAR" = "Los Angeles Rams",
             "SF" = "San Francisco 49ers",
             "LAC" = "Los Angeles Chargers")


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "nfc",
              choices = list("east" = east,
                             "north" = north,
                             "south" = south,
                             "west" = west),
              label = "teams",
              multiple = TRUE),
  textOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$selected <- renderText({paste(input$nfc, collapse = ", ")})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd like for users to be able to select all teams in the NFC East, for example, by clicking "east" in the drop-down menu, or add an option to the list that selects all of the nfc east teams.

note: adding a fifth option, `"all" = c("Dallas Cowboys", "New York Giants", "Washington Redskins", "Philadelphia Eagles")` to `east <- list(..)` would not be ideal as I'd like users to be able to then deselect teams (i.e. select all nfc east teams and then exclude the Cowboys).

Comment: Directly, I don't think there is a way to do it (and I've recently been looking at doing the same with `selectizeInput`). Indirectly (and aesthetically not-as-clean), I think the only way to do it currently is as you say you don't want it (I thought the same thing). Github issue requesting this: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2252

Comment: I would use [shinyTree](https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree), or some similar JS library instead.

Comment: thanks @r2evans. good to know i'm not the only one.

Comment: and good suggestion with shinyTree @GyD. i'm gonna look into it