# Is there a way to select an entire group of choices on a pickerInput from shinyWidgets?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, pickerinput

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    pickerInput("test",choices=list("A"=c(1,2,3,4,5),"B"=c(6,7,8,9,10)),multiple=TRUE),
    textOutput("testOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$testOutput <- renderText({paste(input$test)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I'd like is to click A and have the pickerInput automatically select 1,2,3,4 and 5. Or if we click B, it automatically selects 6,7,8,9, and 10.

Desired output after clicking "A":

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you also want to preserve the ability to select individual elements from each list (e.g., selecting 1,3,5 and 6,7,8)?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, I'd like to have the option to either select the entire group, or individual elements. Or for example select the entire group, and then deselect some elements

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way (though someone else still might!), and with a little research, it looks like this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712090/is-there-a-way-to-select-all-of-a-sub-list-with-shiny-selectinput). However, it doesn't appear there's been much progress - the linked Github request is still open, so maybe the advice in the comments still stands.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I'll check out that link. Also want to add, I'm open to using other packages or base shiny if there's no way to do it in shinyWidgets.

Comment: A promising path... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299185/how-to-pass-shinytree-values-to-drop-down-input-in-shiny

Comment: For `shinywidgets` open issue is here https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/31 . Maybe it is possible with some custom javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use some `JS` to get the result:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- HTML("
$(function() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  function clickHandler(evt) {
    Shiny.setInputValue('group_select', $(this).children('span').text());
  }

  function callback(mutations) {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        $('.dropdown-header').on('click', clickHandler).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        
      }
    }
  }

  let options = {
    childList: true,
  };

  observer.observe($('.inner')[0], options);
})
")

choices <- list("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), "B" = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$head(tags$script(js)),
   pickerInput("test", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE),
   textOutput("testOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$testOutput <- renderText({paste(input$test)})
   
   observeEvent(input$group_select, {
      req(input$group_select)
      updatePickerInput(session, "test", selected = choices[[input$group_select]])
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Explanation

Idea is that you set an `onClick` event for the header line, where you set an `input` variable, upon which you can react in `Shiny`.

The whole `MutationObserver` construct is a crude workaround, because I could not get a (delegated) event listener working.

What I observed is that (not bring an `JavaScript`specialist):

- The content of the dropdown is not generated before the first click. Hence, a direct event listener like `$('.dropdown-header').on()` woudl not work, because the element is not yet existing.
- Event delegation a la `$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-header', ...)` did not work either. I assume that somewhere there is a `stopPropagation` preventing that the event is bubbling up.

Thus, I used the `MutationObserver` to add the `('.drodown-header')` listener the moment it is created. Not the most beautiful nor a resource preserving solution, but at least a working one. Maybe, you can find out how to properly set the event listener w/o the `MutationObsever`.

---

#### Update

If you want to keep all existing selections, you would change the `observeEvent` as follows:

```r
observeEvent(input$group_select, {
   req(input$group_select)
   sel <- union(input$test, choices[[input$group_select]])
   updatePickerInput(session, "test", selected = sel)
})
```

---

### More Background 2022

As this answer was referenced by another question and there was a question in the comments, why we need the `MutationObserver` in the first place, I finally did look up the source code of the input [`bootstrap-select.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.js) and my intuition was right, clicks on the `.dropdown-header` are actively prevented from bubbling up:

```
this.$menuInner.on('click', '.divider, .dropdown-header', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (that.options.liveSearch) {
    that.$searchbox.trigger('focus');
  } else {
    that.$button.trigger('focus');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the answer. I also noted that selecting either of the headers (i.e., "A" or "B') un-selects any active choices in the other header. Is that due to one of the bullets you noted? I know essentially nothing about JS, so I'm probably missing something basic here...

Comment: Well, this is by design. `JavaScript` sends (in this example) eihter `A` or `B` to Shiny. `shiny` decides then to select all elements associated to `A`. If you want another behaviour, it is rather easy to change the `oberserver`...

Comment: I added an update to show how you would chaneg the code to keep existing selections.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for. I figured there was some way to do it in JS that I was unfamiliar with. I've accepted your answer. As a side note, is there some way to deselect a group the same way? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, you can now simply listen to `input$group_select` and do whatever you wan tin your server. It will always return the group label. You may want to change the JS though to `Shiny.setInputValue(..., ..., {priority: "event"}`to make sure `JS` tells `shin` each change.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to add deselecting with your advice. added `{priority: \"event\"}` (had to escape the quotation marks). And then replaced the `sel` line with the following: `if (all(choices[[input$group_select]] %in% input$test)) {
            sel <- input$test[!(input$test %in% choices[[input$group_select]])]
        } else {
            sel <- union(input$test, choices[[input$group_select]])
        }` Hope that helps others with the same problem

Comment: Works like a charm for one `pickerInput`. Has anybody found a way to get this to work for two different `pickerInput` on different tabs in the same shiny app? Not knowing JS, I cannot really tell from the code where to specify different dropdown menus if that's possible at all.

Comment: Hi, is this still working? I tried it out and A and B are not clickable in the dropdown...

Comment: @mandmeier Nope (internal structure of `pickerInput` changed), but I have a solution. However, for some obscure reasons I do not understand, I was not able to edit the post. If you are still interested, you can ask a new question and I will share my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

Ok here's a shot at something for your situation using `jsTreeR`. The code works and does what I think you're looking for, but it's not as pretty as `shinyWidgets`. I imagine there's a way of combining this approach (largely taken from the jsTreeR example in the documentation), and [the approach to create bindings in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315446/2966246) to create something that looks nice and has the functionality you're looking for.

```
library(shiny)
library(jsTreeR)
library(jsonlite)

#create nodes
nodes <- list(
  list(
    text="List A",
    type="root",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "Option 1",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 2",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 3",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 4",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 5",
        type = "child"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text="List B",
    type="root",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "Option 6",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 7",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 8",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 9",
        type = "child"
      ),
      list(
        text = "Option 10",
        type = "child"
      )
    )
  )
)

types <- list(
  root = list(
    icon = "none"
  ),
  child = list(
    icon = "none"
  )
)

#Use in shiny context - example taken from documentation for jsTreeR
ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           jstreeOutput("jstree")
    ),
    column(width = 4,
           tags$fieldset(
             tags$legend("Selections - JSON format"),
             verbatimTextOutput("treeSelected_json")
           )
    ),
    column(width = 4,
           tags$fieldset(
             tags$legend("Selections - R list"), 
             verbatimTextOutput("treeSelected_R")
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output[["jstree"]] <- renderJstree(
    jstree(nodes, checkboxes = TRUE, multiple=TRUE, types=types)
  ) 
  
  output[["treeSelected_json"]] <- renderPrint({
    toJSON(input[["jstree_selected"]], pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
  })
  
  output[["treeSelected_R"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["jstree_selected"]]
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that there's no data attached to the nodes - this just gets the right UI functionality. You'll have to attach values to the nodes that could then be used in downstream calculations.

Comment: Okay this is interesting and I've voted up your answer. It's almost there, is there a way to put this in a dropdown or remove the folder icons? Ideally I'd like to populate the options by a vector or list, instead of typing in "Option 1","Option 2", etc. This is the closest I've seen, spent a few hours looking at options in both shiny and js.

Comment: Included an edit above to get rid of the folder icons - but getting it to show in a dropdown will probably require working with those shiny bindings as shown in that other answer from @StéphaneLaurent. And I'm sure that an `lapply()` approach could generate the right list structure, but I'm not terribly proficient with that kind of thing.