# How to replace choices of PickerInput with "all" when all of them are selected and display them only if "all" is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinywidgets

In the `shiny` app below when all `pickerInput()` choices are selected then instead of their names as choices inside the `pickerInput()` I would like to display the word `"all"` as choice and when you click on it, then all three choices shall be displayed. If we can make it work with `selectInput()` no problem but the printed output should not be affected. How can I do it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  uiOutput("pick"),
  verbatimTextOutput("PR")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$pick<-renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p9",
      label = "Health Insurance",
      choices = unique(as.character(iris$Species)),
      width = "150px",
      selected = unique(as.character(iris$Species)),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(
        `actions-box` = TRUE,
        `deselect-all-text` = "None",
        `select-all-text` = "All",
        `none-selected-text` = "zero"
      )
    )
  })
  output$PR<-renderPrint({
    input$p9
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is an exercise. Do you also have a question?

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: first of all is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. Why do you want to have it? There is already an `All` button and it works (though it is not a choice).

Comment: because my actual list of choices is very large so I do not want it to be displayed unless I press the "All" choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68161333/22180364) good answer. We use a `clickHandler` here which changes the style of the `dropdown-item` between `display: block` and `display: none` depending on when the container `All` is clicked. Note that by the initialisation of the app the items are only hidden behind `All` if all choices are selected.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- HTML(
    "
$(function() {
  let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  function clickHandler(evt) {
    if ($('.dropdown-item').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('.dropdown-item').on('click', clickHandler).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.dropdown-item').on('click', clickHandler).css('display', 'block');
    }
  }

  function callback(mutations) {
      for (let mutation of mutations) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
              $('.dropdown-header').on('click', clickHandler).css('cursor', 'pointer');
              if ($('#p9 option').length == $('#p9 :selected').length) {
                  $('.dropdown-item').on('click', clickHandler).css('display', 'none');
              }
          }
      }
  }

  let options = {
    childList: true,
  };

  observer.observe($('.inner')[0], options);
})
"
)

choices <- list("All" = unique(as.character(iris$Species)))

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(js)),
    pickerInput(
        inputId = "p9",
        label = "Health Insurance",
        choices = choices,
        width = "150px",
        selected = unlist(unname(choices)),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            `deselect-all-text` = "None",
            `select-all-text` = "All",
            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
        )
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("PR")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$PR <- renderPrint({
        input$p9
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```